# how to pass the id from delete button to the popup delete button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, popup, tailwind-css

I have a table in a frontend application where each row represents an item, and for each row, you have a "Remove" button that triggers a warning popup when clicked. In this popup, you want to pass the item's ID, so if the user confirms the deletion, you can delete the corresponding item from the table on the backend.

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
    import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css'
    
    
    const List = () => {
        const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get('/api/institute/instituteInfo')
            .then((response) => {
                setRowData(response.data);
                })
        }, [])
    
        const popupBox = (id) => {
          document.getElementById('deleteBox').style.display='block';
        }
    
        const closePopupBox = () => {
          document.getElementById('deleteBox').style.display='none';
        }
       
        const softDelete = () => {
          axios.delete(`/api/institute/instituteInfo/${id}`)
          .then(() => {
          getData();
      })
        }

    return (




      
    <div className="flex flex-col relative">
    <div className="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
    <div className="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div className="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
    <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <thead className="bg-gray-50">
    <tr>
    <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
     Institute Name
     </th>
     <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
     Domain or Subdomain
     </th>
     <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
     No. of Users
     </th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody className="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
     {rowData.map((data => {
     return (
     <tr key={data._id}>
     <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
     <div className="flex items-center">
                              
     <div className="ml-4">
     <div className="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
     {data.institute_name}
     </div>
     <div className="text-sm text-gray-500">
     {data.institute_address}
     </div>
                                
     <div className="text-sm text-blue mt-1">
     {data.institute_email}
     </div>
     <div className="text-sm text-gray-500">
     {data.institute_phone}
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </td>
     <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
     <div className="text-xs text-gray-900">Domain</div>
     <div className="text-bs text-gray-500">{data.institute_subdomain}</div>
                            
     <div className="text-xs text-gray-900 mt-1">Sub-Domain</div>
     <div className="text-bs text-gray-500">{data.institute_subdomain}</div>
     </td>
                          
     <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
     Admin
     </td>
     <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
     <div className="flex flex-col">
     <button className='border-2 border-color: border-blue-700 text-blue-dark w-28 h-8 mt-6 rounded' 
     type='submit'>Edit</button>
     <button className='border-2 border-color: border-gray-300 w-28 h-8 mt-1 rounded' 
     type='submit' onClick={() => popupBox(data._id)} >Remove</button>
     <button className='border-b-2 border-color: border-gray-500 w-28 h-8 mt-1 rounded' 
     type='submit'>Add to Blacklist</button>
     </div>
     </td>
     </tr>
     )}))}
     </tbody>
     </table>
                     
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     div className={styles.manage}>
     <div id="deleteBox" className='w-11/12 pl-9 hidden'>
     <h1 className='mt-4 font-bold text-lg'>Delete the institute?</h1>
     <p className='text-sm'>You'll lose all contacted data. We can't recover them once you delete.</p>
     <div>
     <textarea id="reasonToDelete" name="reasonToDelete" rows="4" cols="50" 
     className='border-2 border-color: border-gray-300 rounded p-2 mt-4' placeholder="Write the reason to delete"></textarea>
      </div>
       <div  className='mb-10'>
       <button className='border-2 border-color: border-gray-300 w-28 h-8 mt-1 rounded'
       onClick={() => closePopupBox()}>Cancel</button>
       <button className='bg-red-color text-gray-light bg-opacity-75 font-normal w-28 h-8 mt-1 ml-1 rounded' 
       onClick={() => softDelete()}>Yes, delete it</button>
       </div>
       </div>    
       </div>             
     </div>
            
)
 }
```

export default List;

```
      //Home.module.css
.manage {
    margin-top: -64rem;
    margin-left: 50rem;
    background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `getElementById` has nothing to do in a React app, and `.style.display='none'` isn't how you hide an element in React either...

Comment: @JeremyThille  i am new into this. if you can tell me how to do that i will fix that

Comment: Can you show the remaining code for the `List` component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use state here,

set modal id when popup open, pass the state on remove button call.

`const [modalId, setModalId] = useState("");`

when modal closes, reset the state to the default value.

Answer (score 1):

hey bro first by using react  forgot about manipulating  the DOM directly in fact what you should do to have a POPUP alert is using REFS , try to find a youtube video explains how to implement modals in react , second when you have a ref to your modal it's the same as document.getElementByID("deleteBox") "but in react way" now getting that ID is pretty simple what you should do is :
whenever you open that modal (popup) check parent in Ref and get it's ID in a const for example and forward it to your link in axios.